# mocha assert.deepEqual when one of the values is a function?

Tags: javascript, testing, promise, mocha.js

Since functions are first-class objects, and can be passed inside of another js object, how can I do an assert in my tests to be sure I'm getting back the right function?

I'm using Q for promises, and mocha/chai/chai-as-promised for testing. My method returns different functions based on the if/else (I need to either redirect or use a different route).

I'll return something like:

```
fulfill({next: function(res) {return res.render('single-pages/site-map');}});
```

and my test looks like:

```
return assert.becomes(
    page.helpers.checkIfSinglePage('site-map', null), 
    {next: function(res) {return res.render('single-pages/site-map');}}
);
```

but it's telling me that the returned values are not the same.

```
AssertionError: expected { next: [Function] } to deeply equal { next: [Function] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are compared by reference in JavaScript.

```
(function(){}) === (function(){}); // false
```

In fact, this is because functions are objects. At the moment (until ES7) everything in JavaScript except primitive value types (number, string, null, undefined, bool) is a reference and compares with reference equality checks.

You technically *can* check the two functions as two strings (comparing the code) and (assuming no old versions of firefox) it *will* compare equal for the same function - but that's a poor indication since two functions can mean opposite things:

```
var foo = (function(){
x = alert;
return function foo(){ x(); } // first function
})();

var bar = (function(){
x = console.log.bind(console,"BAR");
return function foo(){ x(); } // first function
})();
foo.toString() === bar.toString(); // true, but an incorrect check.
```

So to conclude, there is no way to know in JavaScript if two do the same without having a reference to them.

Instead, you can call `.next` and check that the rendered valuer is the same.